# How can I stop Outlook from expanding subfolders when they receive mail?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have several rules which mark items as read and then send them to a specific folder. Nearly all of these folders are nested within one parent folder.

The issue is that usually when I get one of these messages, Outlook will expand the parent folder. I have no need for this sort of notification. The entire point of me automatically marking messages as read is that I don't need to know about them.

Can I stop Outlook from auto-expanding folders when they get new mail? I get dozens of these messages a day, and it's frustrating to constantly close this folder only to have it reopen minutes later.

I'm using Outlook 2010.

Comment: Do you find that this happens if you are using "Folder List" instead of "Mail" for that pane?

Comment: Just tried it under "Folder List" and it appears to still be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the folders only expand when I have my rules set to mark items as read. If the rules simply move the items to folders, but leave them unread, the folders don't expand. I suspect this is because marking them as read makes the rule a "client-only rule" which means it only runs when the client is open.

I find this to be a particularly annoying aspect of Outlook and Exchange. Because I got tired of constantly collapsing my folders, I decided to turn off the mark-as-read parts of my rules. And because I want all my read, I wrote a program which communicates with Exchange and recursively marks all items as read. I set this program to run every minute using Task Scheduler.

If you would like to use the same program, you can [find the source code here](https://github.com/krispharper/MarkExchangeItemsAsRead). You will need Visual Studio to compile it. You will also need to download and install the Exchange Web Services API [from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35371).

Incidentally, this also solves the problem I had [in this question](https://superuser.com/q/335122/93363) where Outlook would constantly tell me I had unread mail when I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Too sad, but you cannot change this behaviour. The only way do disable folder auto-expansion is to use server-side rules. These rules are available when using Outlook + Exchange Server. Unfortunately, the limited subset of conditions and actions is available in server-side rules.

Comment: Why would it be server side? This seems like purely a client issue. Am I missing something?

Comment: This *is* a client issue. This is why server-side rules do the trick: Exchange Server manages all the actions leaving Outlook unaware.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  I'm not certain that my rules are server or client side, but:  A)  I can create a rule (such as "permanently delete mail from a certain person") and when I save it, I get a popup that says it's client-side rule and and will only run with Outlook is open,  B)  I have other rules that don't give me that popup (so I assume they are server-side), but C) those rules (in B) still cause the folder auto-expansion to happen.  Does that make sense?  How can I specify a rule to be server-side vs. client-side?

Comment: Ok, I figured out one problem - many of my rules had "stop processing more rules" which I guess makes it a client-side rule.  I removed that so they're all server-side now.  But they are still making the folders expand - are you sure about your answer?

Comment: Completely sure.

Answer (score 1):

I finally made my Outlook folder stop opening every time I get a new email!

I went to **RULES** > **MANAGE RULES**.

I found the rule that was affecting that email, and for that rule, I **unchecked** the option called **"ON THIS COMPUTER ONLY"**.

A few minutes later, I checked, and sure enough - I had received emails in the folder. It stopped opening automatically.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a screenshot for each step of the process you went through?

Comment: None of my rules had this box checked. This solution does not work for me.

Comment: I can't change to server-side rules because my rules are pulling mail into a local PST file.  ...I ended up just rearranging things, moving all of folders that I want to automatically file mail to into a single subfolder.  That way, at least there is just one subfolder that I have to leave open as mail trickles down throughout the day.

Answer (score 1):

I have also had this annoying issue with Outlook.  I like some of the solutions above, but I am not an admin on my work computer, so I have resorted to moving those folders which I need Client-Only Rules to move emails to (which are marked as read) back out to the top level under Inbox.  I use punctuation as a prefix to sort these folders (you could use numbers as well) so that I can send the unimportant ones to the bottom of the list.  ie !Meetings #Projects $Service Tickets etc.

If the "subfolder" is no longer nested nothing expands.  I know this is not a great solution, just a work-around.